# How to override only one variable inside parent class's method?

Tags: python, overriding

Let's suppose that `Parent` class is:

```py
class Parent:

  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def do_something(self):
    a = self.a
    b = self.a
    print('The a is ', a)
    print('The b is ', b)
```

I want to create a `Child` class that will redefine only `b`

Something like:

```
class Child(Parent):

  def do_something(self, custom_param):
    @some_exotic_decorator_or_something_else(b=custom_param)
    super().do_something()
```

And get output like:

```
obj = Child('the_a')
obj.do_something('the_b')
```

```
The a is the_a
The b is the_b
```

Of course original method has many lines and complicated logic to override whole method. Also that is one of common python libraries so I want to minimise intrusion inside method.

Here is any common way in python to do that?

To be more clear, the method what I want to override is [`_write_end_record`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62a8a0c5223f750e22ee381d3cfbdb718cf1cc93/Lib/zipfile.py#L1858)

I want to redefine only `centDirOffset`. All other logic is working good. I may copy and paste whole method inside my code and change only one line, but it don't looking like a smart idea

Comment: Not really… functions are opaque objects that you can't easily reach into the modify individual variables or lines or anything else. — Yes, it's probably possible with enough bending over backwards, but this *really* shouldn't be your first goto solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that the parent class is not yours, but something in an existing library?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yep. added additional information after `To be more clear`

Answer (score 1):

A clean and easy way would be to make your parent class more general by adding a parameter to your method and assign a default value to it.

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def do_something(self, b=None):
        if b is None:
            b = self.a
        a = self.a
        print('The a is ', a)
        print('The b is ', b)
```

By doing this, you do not even need a child class.

Comment: Okay. I added exact Class and method that I want to override inside question. Any ideas how to `make it more general`?

Comment: @rzlvmp [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858147/how-to-modify-imported-source-code-on-the-fly) might lead you where you want, but I do not consider this as a nice way to code.

Comment: I solved my problem using another [strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70388239/13946204). But I still looking for way how to partially override existing methods. Link mentioned before don't have answer how to do that

Comment: @rzlvmp As deceze indicates, this is getting quite involved. My idea was to import the function you want and modify it while importing using regexp. This way you can overwrite the value used for `centDirOffset`. The thread offers some strategies to achieve this. But I don't see why you should do this. You make yourself depended on the actual sourcecode (not only on the behavior) of the imported function and on future changes of it. In my eyes this is a recipe for future disaster. Instead hang on with a one time CTRL-C + CTRL-V and you will be fine for a long time.